# Can I use a Pentax lens on a Canon body?

Tags: lens, canon, film, pentax, lens-mount

I have a SMC Pentax-M 50mm 1:2 prime lens and a Pentax MC auto 28mm 1:2.8 from my dad. I have been looking at two *film cameras* lately, the Pentax MG and the Canon AE-1. If I buy the Pentax MG I know I can use the lenses. If I buy the Canon AE-1, can I still use these two lens? Or do I need to use an adaptor?

Comment: Note that while many Pentax lenses of that era are great, the 50mm f/2 is not very exciting. It's basically the very cheap kit lens of its era. If you had the 50mm f/1.8 or f/1.4 that's be worth adapting, but in my opinion this one really isn't unless you have some special compelling reason. The 28mm lens you describe is also not particularly valuable — copies described as perfect go for under $5 on ebay. I'm all for playing with old cameras and lenses (and I love Pentax lenses!) but I wouldn't hinge your decision around the ones you have.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do decide to scrounge up other old Pentax lenses, an is that they can be used on modern Pentax DSLRs with no adaptor, whereas FD lenses can't easily be mounted to modern Canon bodies even with an adaptor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an adapter to mount Pentax K-mount lenses on any Canon camera body.  The AE-1 is a Canon FD mount, so a search on Google for Pentax K to Canon FD will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You will not find a Pentax K lens to Canon fd camera adapter.  The other way around yes, but I have looked everywhere, B&H, ebay, etc.  Don't let these guys mislead you.  They can't be found.  If you buy an AE1 you will not be able to use your Pentax lenses.

Answer (score 0):

An adapter is all you should need. B&H (bhphotovideo.com) has nearly every camera-lens adapter you can find. For example, you can get a $10 adapter canon to nikon, but you lose autofocus. if you really feel the need, you can spend $100-$300 and use autofocus.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made an adapter using an FD body cap and a PK lens mount.
http://anaussiebrekkie.com/2017/03/22/proof-of-concept-pk-lens-to-fd-body-adapter/

Comment: Can you please extend your answer, provide some details as this web page can disappear in the future?

Answer (score -2):

I'm presently using a Pentax 50mm f/1.4 and a Pentax 28mm f/2.8 lens on my Canon EOS 550D with the help of an adapter. Brand name of the adapter is Kiwifotos (jjc). Both of these lenses are great, you will master manual focus with training. The Pentax lenses I have are K mount. Thus I bought a Pentax K mount to Canon EF adapter. You can find them on ebay. but beware there are lot of cheap adapters which wont focus infinity.

Comment: @baisun Note that this answer is for significantly different situation from yours: the Canon AE-1 uses the older FD mount, so do *not* buy a Pentax K to Canon EF adapter as it won't work for you.

Comment: Full frame Canon EOS cameras have an issue with the mirror hitting the back of the lens for some Pentax lenses.